# Bubble sort returning long integer in C

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I have defined my int array like so in main, followed by a function call for the bubble sort:

```
int numarr[6] = { 6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2 };
int arrsize = 6;

bubblesort(&numarr[0], arrsize);
```

My bubble sort function looks like this:

```
int bubblesort(int num[], int x) {
    int temp, j, i;

    for (j = 0; j < x; j++ ) {
        for (i = 0; i < x - j; i++) {
            if (num[i] > num[i + 1]) {
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[i + 1];
                num[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Every now and then the output would come out perfectly but other times, I will find that when I call each one manually, `numarr[0]` contains a long integer. It would look like this

```
-997049053, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

And incase you're wondering, I tracked it after the function call like so:

```
printf(" %d,", num[0]);
printf("%d, ", num[1]);
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: Crazy numbers like that are usually a sign you have gone beyond the bounds of your array somewhere.  Try printing out i and i+1 in each step (or watching them in a debugger) and see if a number larger than 5 appears.

Comment: Try x-j-1 in the second loop

Comment: This is a fine example to work on when you're learning, but once you've learned how control flow and array indexing work, please forget about bubble sort forever, as it's a terrible algorithm for real work.  Eventually you'll want to learn how to use `qsort`.

Comment: actually, for small arrays (say less than 10 entries) bubble sort, insertion sort, etc are excellent choices.  However, when the array size expands beyond ~10 entries, the number of comparisons being made makes bubble sort, etc more expensive to use.  that is when a qsort, mergesort, sieve sort, etc really begin to shine.

Answer (score 3):

When `i = x - 1`, `num[i + 1]` is out of range and must not be accessed.

Try using `for (j = 1; j < x; j++ )` instead of `for (j = 0; j < x; j++ )`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, this fixed it pretty much.

Comment: Your array is declared a `numarr` and called `num` later.
Anyway  you dont need "address of" and indexing, just call

    `bubblesort(numarr, arrsize);`

Answer (score 1):

here is a correct algorithm for a bubble sort.

Notice the significant difference between the posted code algorithm and the the following.  Especially notice the limiting of the index variables `c` and `d` in the `for()` statements:

```
void bubblesort( int num[], int x)
{
    int c;
    int d;
    int swap;


    for (c = 0 ; c < ( x - 1 ); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0 ; d < (x - c - 1); d++)
        {
            if (num[d] > num[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
            {
                swap     = num[d];
                num[d]   = num[d+1];
                num[d+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```